# Set up [apachesolr] as synonym of [solr]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

The [solr](/questions/tagged/solr) tag currently has around 1,500 questions. The [apachesolr](/questions/tagged/apachesolr) tag has a measly 74, and since these are obviously the same thing (note [the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/solr/info) in the tag-wiki), could someone with sufficient power merge those to clear up the confusion?

Comment: Or perhaps just make [tag:apache-solr] -> [tag:solr]

Comment: I think that was what I meant to say – so that `solr` is the correct tag – the name is unique by itself, so `apache` is just noise in this regard.